# How to correctly groupByKey for non pairwiseRDDs using pyspark

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, pyspark, rdd

I'm new to Python. I'm also new to pysaprk. I'm trying to run a code that takes a tuple of tuple that looks like this `(id , (span, mention))` to perform `.map(lambda (id, (span, text)): (id, text))`.

The code I'm working with is:

```
 m = text\
            .map(lambda (id, (span, text)): (id, text))\
            .mapValues(lambda v: ngrams(v, self.max_ngram))\'''error triggered here'''
            .flatMap(lambda (target, tokens): (((target, t), 1) for t in tokens))\
```

This how the original data is formatted `(id, source, span, text)`:

```
 {'_id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerambycidae',
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plinthocoelium_virens',
  'span': (61, 73),
  'text': u'"Plinthocoelium virens" is a species of beetle in the family Cerambycidae.'},
 {'_id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dru_Drury',
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plinthocoelium_virens',
  'span': (20, 29),
  'text': u'It was described by Dru Drury in 1770.'}]
```

I get this error:

```
 for k, v in iterator:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

I know groupByKey work on pairwiseRDDs, so I would like to know how to correctly perform groupByKey to resolve this issue?

Any help or guidance will be truly appreciated.

I'm using python 2.7 and pyspark 2.3.0.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. Why do you need to groupByKey? What is the problem with the code you have posted?

Comment: @user3689574 This code is the first part of calculating tfidf. when ngram line called it causes the above error. Please let me know if I should provide further info regarding the code or the error.

Comment: Does "mentions" has the dict you are showing above as rows?

Comment: @user3689574 What do you mean by rows? it runs on pyspark so to print that dict I did `mentions.take(2)`

Comment: @user3689574 I think this transformed to another issue, should I edit back the question and select your post as an answer and then post another question?

Comment: I think I can help here. From the code above, you don't need "span", correct?

Comment: If so, try: mentions.map(lambda x: (x["_id"],  x["text"])).groupByKey().mapValues(lambda v: ngrams(v, self.max_ngram))

Comment: @user3689574  After grouping each "text" with its "span" we need to keep only the "_id" and "text". Then next line takes the tuple then performs ngram. So we dont need span at the end but the API method takes the "text" and "span" as a tuple.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the API method takes" but this line: .map(lambda (target, (span, text)): (target, text)) shows you are not using the "span" and so you can try and run the code in my previous comment

Comment: Just tried it, it caused the same `UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment` which I believe is another issue right? The data formulation is correct now but this is another problem since it passes the ngram line but produces another error?

Comment: This is an API that i'm using which seems to have some conflicts to different pushed versions. I dont know :)

Comment: I can't find the code you are running in ngrams (http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/util.html#ngrams)

Comment: @user3689574 No it's a different API. Here you go https://github.com/wikilinks/sift the method I'm trying to work with is in text.py called `EntityMentionTermFrequency`. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to map the data into a form that has a key and value and then [groupByKey](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=groupbykey#pyspark.RDD.groupByKey).

A key and value form is always a tuple (a, b) with the key being a and value b. a and b may be tuples themselves.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([{'_id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerambycidae',
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plinthocoelium_virens',
  'span': (61, 73),
  'text': u'"Plinthocoelium virens" is a species of beetle in the family Cerambycidae.'},
 {'_id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dru_Drury',
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plinthocoelium_virens',
  'span': (20, 29),
  'text': u'It was described by Dru Drury in 1770.'},
 {'_id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dru_Drury',
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plinthocoelium_virens2',
  'span': (20, 29, 2),
  'text': u'It was described by Dru Drury in 1770.2'}])

print rdd.map(lambda x: (x["_id"], (x["span"], x["text"]))).groupByKey()\
.map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1]))).collect()
```

> [(u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dru_Drury', [((20, 29), u'It was described
>   by Dru Drury in 1770.'), ((20, 29, 2), u'It was described by Dru Drury
>   in 1770.2')]), (u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerambycidae', [((61, 73),
>   u'"Plinthocoelium virens" is a species of beetle in the family
>   Cerambycidae.')])]

Comment: Thank you, but it's causing a new error in the next line which performs the ngram (I edited the question to show the code and error), I dont know what format the next line is expecting. Thank you in so much.